# How to generate a local Database file from an Entity Data Model (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I'm working on a joint project and have been tasked with creating a test-data solution. Basically I want to have an Entity Data Model in the source-control that each person can use to create a local Database file hosted on their own machine that can then be populated with the contents of an XML doc also in the source-control.

They can then run their tests against that local test database file without touching anyone else's data, and can wipe/reset it freely.

I've successfully created the `.edmx`, and selected "Generate Database from Model" to create the `.edmx.sql` script but when I try to run it I get "The database does not exist" which makes no sense to me because I assumed the whole point of this process was to create the Database using the Schema defined in the EDM.

Here is the [solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Seb04.png) for context

Here is the content of the [SQL file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nwbg.png) generated by "Generate Database from Model"

And here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM4RR.png) I get when I run it

I am not extremely experienced with Entity or SQL so there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Use `context.Database.Create()`.

Comment: @GertArnold I cannot locate this method. 

Here is the fully expanded content of my edm: https://i.imgur.com/3QcwhDl.png 

and the content of my Context.cs file: https://i.imgur.com/BiPnVlq.png         Is the Create method something I will need to make myself? Or should it be accessible somewhere in the code generated by the EDM?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx